# error in awk/sed usage of file manipulation line-by-line

Tags: sed, awk

I have a requirement of appending the string `" 1"` at the end of every line of the file. After the execution of below two commands, an empty file is created.

```
awk '{ print $0 " 1" }' < file.txt > file.txt
```

using `sed`

```
sed 's/$/ 1/' file.txt > file.txt
```

What is the mistake attempted here, can you please advise ? I am executing these commands in mac terminal.

Comment: Thanks for that, I learnt that as well. Could you please help me in my query which is different 'not able to append the string at the end of each line' ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GNU `sed` solution needs `-i` for inline editing:

```
sed -i 's/$/ 1/' file.txt
```

(With BSD `sed`, you need `sed -i ''`)

In `awk`, you have to work around that with a temporary file:

```
awk '{ print $0 " 1" }' file.txt > tmp && mv tmp file.txt
```

In fact, `sed` also creates a temporary file, but `-i` handles that

**The Problem with `awk '{ print $0 " 1" }' < file.txt > file.txt`:**

The redirections were performed before `awk` get the control. `> file.txt` will truncate the file. Try in a terminal:

```
>file
```

The `file` will be zero sized, even if before the file had contents. So `awk` has no data to read from that file. That's the same problem as with `sed`.

Final solution with `\r` line breaks:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\r\n|\n|\r/ 1\n/g' file.txt
```

Comment: I assume that I can't use the same filename for both input and output. So i tried the following two commands using awk `awk '{ print $0 " 1" }' < file.txt > file_new.txt` and `awk '{ print $0 " 1" }' < file.txt > tmp && mv tmp file.txt `. The string has only been appended to the last line of the files not to every line. Meanwhile `sed` command `sed -i'' 's/$/ 1/' file_IDs.txt` gave an error `sed: 1: "file_ ...": extra characters at the end of f command`. Do the file shouldn't contain `_` in it's name?

Comment: @Prradep sry, the sed command in osx needs a space between `-i` and `''`, I updated the answer

Comment: Thanks @chaos. After changing the `sed` command, the output is same like the `awk` command. Only the last line of the file is updated with the string pattern not every line .

Comment: @Prradep I tested it, for me it adds the string to every line. Can you give a sample of your file to test?

Comment: Yeah, it worked fine for test file which i created myself but not for the real file. `$ head file.txt 
123
123
2334
345
345
23456
123
123
2334
345
` this is the test file. When use `head real_file.txt` it is printing only the last line as output. As a beginner, I have no idea on the error.

Comment: @Prradep Your `real_file.txt` has only one line. Therefore head prints only that one line and the awk/sed command add only one string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26465/discussion-between-prradep-and-chaos).